# In Linux: Importing of Existing PDF Forms and Adding Submit Buttons

Tags: forms, pdf, submit, form-submit

I'm trying to save post data from a PDF file to my web server. I don't have commonly available Windows tools, because I'm on Linux.

When using Linux software like Scribus, I am not able to successfully import the existing PDFs correctly... these are often critically accurate legal documents, which must appear exactly the way they've been designed.

I've used a web application (PDFecape.com) to add form fields to the PDF... I've autopopulated these fields on the server before showing the user. This application does not allow for a submit button.

I then used "Wine" to run Windows software called Soda PDF to add a submit button and a URL for submission.

It uses Javascript to submit the form, which from what I've read, seems to be the right approach. However, the server is not being pinged by PDFs when the button is pressed.

The URL for submission is a simple PHP script that saves post content as a PDF and sends me an email.

I've tried it in Ubuntu's built in PDF document viewer, Chrome's built in PDF reader, and have download Adobe's Acrobat Reader to try submitting with that as well.

In each case, the server is not being pinged.

Is there another way to add a submit button to this form? Any other ideas?

Thanks,
Jason Silver

Comment: This link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485670/pdf-form-submission) is close, but not for Linux. I don't have Windows, nor access to it.

Comment: Well, I hired someone who uses Windows to do this. They've been able to successfully add a submit button to all my PDFs which actually transfers the full saved PDF file to the server, where I am able to store it in a database. I'm not sure if I should delete this question now?? It's not technically solved.